# A single word for someone who is fluent in only one foreign language?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know you can say bilingual, trillingual, multilingual. But what if I want to emphasise the number (**only one**) of foreign language, rather than the total number of languages one can speak?

Answer (score 4):

Someone who is only fluent in one *foreign language* means that he/she is fluent in two languages. That is, he/she is fluent in his/her mother tongue  which he/she has grown up listening and speaking since birth, and the other language can be any (foreign) language spoken within the country he/she comes from or spoken in any other countries. For example, a person born in Sri Lanka listens and speaks the language 'Tamil' since birth. Then,Tamil is his/her  mother tongue. If he/she can speak another *local language* called 'Sinhala', then Sinhala is his/her foreign language, or if he/she can speak the language 'Hindi' which is generally not used in Sri Lanka can also be the foreign language. 
In summary, who is only fluent in one foreign language which is spoken within the country or any other countries can be called a 'bilingual'.

Comment: Nice explanation but your answer is the same as that of @Ricky who posted it an hour before you. If you have to offer the same answef, kindly use the comments section and upvote the answer already provided.

Comment: @vickyace Balderdash. Ricky's answer has no explanation and no illustration. It's not the answer that counts it's the explanation. This is a completely different answer!!!

Comment: @AraucariaMan hmm. Agreed.

Comment: @vickyace It's good to agree :)

Answer (score 1):

**bilingual**

able to speak two languages with the facility of a native speaker

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bilingual?s=t

There are also trilingual, quadrilingual, and multilingual people.

Comment: What if I want to emphasise the number (only one) of foreign language, rather than the total number of languages one can speak?

Comment: Foreign, domestic, what do you think we are, xenophobes? We don't discriminate among languages. A person who only speaks one language is called monolingual (although some folks prefer "illiterate").

Comment: Don't be a Social Justice Warrior, OK? Obviously one's language levels can be different. Is it that hard to wrap your head around the idea that someone has a language or two as their mother tongue, and another fluent enough but not native?

Comment: That's not bilingual; more like having bilingual pretensions. Oh, and the above was something called "humor." Just saying.